# jQuery remove checkbox and associated label

Tags: jquery, label, removeall

I have the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="oDiv" id="Parent"  name="divcorp[]" value="Parent"/>
<label for="Parent">Parent</label>
```

I can remove the `checkbox` using the following, which works correctly:

```
$( "#Parent" ).remove();
```

However, how could I also remove the associated label for this checkbox?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [attribute equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XN6Jm/2/)**

```
$('label[for=Parent]').remove();
```

> **Description**: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a
>   value exactly equal to a certain value.

Comment: Given that `label`s are the only elements with the `for` attribute (or `htmlFor` property), you might as well specify the `label` in the selector, and avoid the implied universal selector (just to cut down on the work that has to be done to find the element).

Comment: That's great - thanks - as an aside, is it possible to remove them based on where they are? - using equals, such as `:eq(6)`

Comment: $('label[for="Parent"]').remove(); "" missing

Comment: Thanks, these are not really required in this particular case. Try it without double quotes

Answer (score 1):

If the `id` of element is not known, but its `value` is known and the `id` of its parent is known, the following can be done

Code ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XN6Jm/39/)):

```
<div id="payment">
    <input id="RANDOM_GENERATED-1" type="checkbox" name="div[]" value="0" />
    <label for="RANDOM_GENERATED-1">Pay Now by CC</label><br/>

    <input id="RANDOM_GENERATED-2" type="checkbox" name="div[]" value="1" />
    <label for="RANDOM_GENERATED-2">Pay Now by PayPal</label><br/>

    <input id="RANDOM_GENERATED-3" type="checkbox" name="divo[]" value="2" />
    <label for="RANDOM_GENERATED-3">Pay Later by Check</label><br/>

    <input id="RANDOM_GENERATED-4" type="checkbox" name="divo[]" value="2"/>
    <label for="RANDOM_GENERATED-4">Pay Later by Cash</label><br/>
</div>
```

And now if one wanted to remove all the pay later elements (along with label elements), the ones with value `2`

```
$('#payment').find("input[value=2]").each(function () {
    $(this).remove();
    $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').remove();
});
```